# what is the reason for my raspberry pi 3 camera stops working after few hours?

Tags: raspberry-pi3

i am trying to take a long video that is week long with 6 raspberry pi 3 cameras. every camera is connected to electricity port with through a regular phone transformer that connects each 2 usb ports for the raspberries. i start the shooting using ssh from my computer and i can see the cameras log when each camera shoots a frame at the terminal log. the problem is that each time that i start a long run that is longer than several hours, some cameras deferentially just stop shooting, every time a different camera, and with no perticular reason. are there common reasons for cameras to stop shooting? maybe memory problem? or electricity problem?
would love to hear about a lead so i could check it.
thanks in advance

Comment: You seem to have two leads already, did you check them?

Comment: The hub must be powered by a wall outlet.

Comment: the transformator is connected to a wall outlet. i wonder how to check the memory lead and if it is a common one?